# Hosting my website with a different hosting service

Tags: ftp, dns, hosting

Here is what I'm sure is a dumb question but I cannot find an answer for.

I purchased a domain name from 1and1 WITHOUT any hosting. I was intending to set it up on my own server which fell through, so I decided that I was just gonna do traditional hosting.

I found a great deal and promotion at Dreamhost for a year of hosting, so I signed up for the hosting service.

Through the 1and1 control panel, I have redirected to the Dreamhost name servers, but I'm not really sure what to do next.

How do I now upload my website files to Dreamhost and load them when visiting the domain that I purchased from 1and1?

I understand this may be vague, and I apologize if so, just want some guidance. Let me know if there is any information I can give to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purchasing your domain through 1and1 is no problem. I'm not extremely familiar with either company or their infrastructure but I can give you a general guideline with an attempt to tailor it to your needs. Hopefully you'll find this helpful.

First step I would personally take would be to update your nameservers at 1and1 to use Dreamhost's. If they are using cpanel, this may be a requirement. Regardless of their control panel, this will likely be the easiest way to manage any updates you need to make. After this you will only need to login to 1and1 to renew your domain or transfer it.

To change your name servers:

1) Log in to the 1&1 Control Panel using your Customer ID OR domain name and your password.

2) Click the Domains link from the Domains & Webspace panel.

3) Check the box next to the domain to select it and click Show DNS Settings from the DNS drop-down box above the list of domains.

4) Click the Edit button next to Name Server Settings.

5) If you are currently using a CNAME with the domain, you will not be able to set which name servers should be used with the domain unless you select DNS from General settings. 
Select My name server from the Name server drop-down box.

6) Enter the first name server address into the Primary name server text box.
Select My secondary name server from the Secondary name server drop-down box to add a second address.
Enter the second name server address into the 1st secondary name server text box.
You may add a third and fourth name server address if necessary, but only two are required.
Click the OK button to save your settings.

For step 6, you should be entering the following name servers (unless Dreamhost has provided different servers when you opened your account): ns1.dreamhost.com, ns2.dreamhost.com, ns3.dreamhost.com

Note: you may only be able to enter two of the three listed.

Next you need to login to your Dreamhost  control panel for hosting. Ensure you have your domain added. If not, go to Manage Domains and add your domain. It should provide instructions for adding your domain. If you plan to have everything hosted at Dreamhost (as it sounds to me like you do) but sure to selected "Fully Hosted." You can manager your DNS through their domain manager once you are using their nameservers. You can add A records if needed to point to your IP but generally in shared hosting environments, the control panel will perform the basic configuration of the A records for your site.

As always with DNS, it may take some time for your changes to propagate. You may want to flush your dns as well (on your local machine).

edit: Sorry I just re-read your question and realized you accomplished what I answered. Here's some additional steps to get your website up and running:

Are you using a static HTML website? If you are using Wordpress or another CMS/Application, please let me know as the instructions will vary for those types of installs.

If it is a static website, download an FTP Client, if you do not have one already. My personal recommendation is FileZilla, simply because it is free and easy to use but any FTP Client will work. Log back into your DreamHost control panel and look for your server information under "Account Status." It will say "Your Web Server:" followed by the name of the server your account is on. Enter that server name into FileZilla for the IP/Host. Try using your controlpanel login and password and the port would be 21 for standard FTP. If your login does not work, go back to your control panel and look for an option called "FTP Accounts." Go into this section and create a new FTP account. Now use that account for your user and password in FileZilla. This should normally drop you into your website's home folder. If not, look for anything such as "html", "public_html", "www" and upload your files there. Ensure you have an index.html or index.php file.

If you have any additional questions, please let me know and I can update my response to address them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, turns out I had the wrong password and the DNS didn't propagate until now! Thanks for the very detailed response!

Answer (score 0):

In order for your site to show up from the Dreamhost hosting, you will need to set the A-record in your DNS at 1and1 to resolve to the IP address that is provided by Dreamhost. Making changes to your 1and1 DNS is not part of my expertise (I work at Dyn), but if you have any trouble, their support team should be able to assist.

Good luck!
CL